# How do I do this in typescript/adonis?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found an example on bitbucket of paginating the results of a query, but it was written in java script, and I'm having a little trouble declaring the types.

and getting this error on this line

const pagination:TPagination = usersResults.toJSON()

The type '{ meta: any; data: ModelObject[]; }' does not have the following properties of type

```
        ***sample code****
          async index ({ view, params, request, response }) {
            const page = params.page || 1
            const search = request.input('search') || ''
            const employees = await Employee.query()
                                            .where('name', 'LIKE', '%' + search + '%')
                                            .paginate(page, 10)
            const pagination = employees.toJSON()
            pagination.route = 'employees.pagination'
            if(pagination.lastPage < page && page != 1) {
              response.route(pagination.route, { page: 1 }, null, true)
            }
            else {
              pagination.offset = (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.perPage
              pagination.search = search
              return view.render('employees.index', { employees: pagination })
            }
          }

        }
         ***my code***
        public async searchByName ({request,params, response}: HttpContextContract) {   
                interface TPagination {
                    route: string;
                    lastPage: number;
                    offset:number;
                    search:string;
                    page:number;
                    perPage:number;
                    [key: string]: any;
                    meta: any;
                    data: ModelObject[];

                           
                } 
                try {
                    const page = params.page || 1
                    const search = request.input('search') || ''
                    const usersResults = await User.query()
                                                    .where('name', 'LIKE', '%' + search + '%')
                                                    .orWhere('cns','LIKE','%'+   search +'%')
                                                    .paginate(page, 10)
                    const pagination:TPagination = usersResults.toJSON()
                    pagination.route = 'pagination.users'
                    if(pagination.lastPage < page && page != 1) {
                        response.redirect().toRoute(pagination.route, { page: 1 })
                    }
                    else {
                      pagination.offset = (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.perPage
                      pagination.search = search
                    }

                } catch {
                    return response.status(400).json('{"error":"Usuário não encontrado!"}');
                }
            
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but for future reference.
The function toJSON() only returns a ModelObject type because you can add or remove different keys to the main object. That means that it might not be exactly the same as the object of the query.

In your case you can request the rows directly from the paginate object by:

```
const pagination:TPagination = usersResults.all()
```

The `all()` function of the paginate will return all objects on the current page, with the correct type.

Hope this helps!

P.S. found solution at: https://github.com/adonisjs/lucid/blob/efed38908680cca3b288d9b2a123586fab155b1d/src/Database/Paginator/SimplePaginator.ts#L20